# Google Identity Service Sign In with Google button flicker

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin, google-identity

I am trying to use the Sign In with Google button from the Google Identity Service. Each time I render one of the [Sign In with Google buttons](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview) the font flickers.

The flickering seems to coincide with style changes of text within the google button. It turns out that the google button has 2 spans that hold identical text for the button label. One of these spans is set to display: none. When toggled to be visible, one can see that the flicker seems to be caused by the switching between these two spans for the label. [Google Button on DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFF4D.png).

The Google default font is Roboto, but after the flicker, the font of the span rendered is:

`font-family: Gotham,system-ui,-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe UI,Roboto,Oxygen,Ubuntu,Cantarell,Droid Sans,Helvetica Neue,sans-serif;`

It looks like the hidden button-label span does  have the Roboto font applied though. Could this have something to do with the fonts?

Is there any known way to resolve this flicker?

I have attempted using useMemo in order to resolve this but, so far I have not had any success.

Answer (score 0):

Use a solution like this https://daveceddia.com/useeffect-triggers-every-change/

1. Create a state that holds the `GsiButtonConfiguration`, like `gsiButtonConfiguration` and `setGsiButtonConfigurationState`
2. Modify `setGsiButtonConfigurationState` inside `useCallback` to the value of `gsiButtonConfigurationProp` with `gsiButtonConfigurationProp` as a dependency
3. Run `window.google.accounts.id.renderButton` in `useEffect` with `gsiButtonConfiguration`, the state, as the dependency
4. Since the state won’t change, because `useCallback` didn’t see a diff, the `useEffect` won’t run every time

```
const Base = ({
  gsiButtonConfiguration: gsiButtonConfigurationProp = {
    logo_alignment: 'left',
    shape: 'pill',
    size: 'large',
    text: 'continue_with',
    theme: 'outline',
    type: 'standard',
  },
}: {
  gsiButtonConfiguration?: GsiButtonConfiguration;
}) => {
  const [gsiButtonConfiguration, setGsiButtonConfiguration] =
    useState<GsiButtonConfiguration>(gsiButtonConfigurationProp);

  const buttonRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useCallback(() => {
    setGsiButtonConfiguration(gsiButtonConfigurationProp);
  }, [gsiButtonConfigurationProp]);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.google.accounts.id.renderButton(
      buttonElement: buttonRef.current,
      gsiButtonConfiguration,
    );
  }, [gsiButtonConfiguration]);

  return (<div ref={buttonRef} />);
};
```